# High Cap value of ⌈3.02⌉

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was in a dilemma on finding out the value of ⌈3.02⌉.

From one of the teaching staff I got to know that ⌈3.02⌉ is 4.... Even if it is ⌈1.0001⌉ also it is 2.

But from the other teaching staff I got to know that ⌈3.02⌉ is 3.

I don't know which one is correct.

Can anyone from here clarify my doubt please.

Thanks

Comment: It's four. Do you know the definition of the notation you're using?

Comment: Thanks for confirming the value @T.Bongers. By the way what do you mean by the notation?

Comment: The brackets you're putting around the number. They're called the ceiling function, and you should go look up the definition and make sure you actually understand it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By definition, the ceiling function of $x$ is defined as

> The smallest integer $n$ such that $n\geq x$.

So, let's see what that definition means for $x=3.02$. Can $\lceil x \rceil = 3$? Well, that would mean that $3\geq3.02$, but that is clearly not true.

So, $\lceil x \rceil $ must be $4$ or more. Can it be $4$?

- Is $4\geq 3.02$? **yes**.
- Is $4$ the smallest such number? **yes**, because any smaller number would be smaller than or equal to $3$, so it would be smaller than $3.02$.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain the vote?